# NSLayoutAttributeCenterY With NSLayoutAttributeHeight of UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I created a FOR loop to get 5 Uilabel. The spacing between the uilabels is controlled by NSLayoutConstraint in this way

```
NSInteger max = [[_yValueArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"] integerValue];
NSInteger min = [[_yValueArray valueForKeyPath:@"@min.self"] integerValue];

for (NSInteger value = max; value >= min; value -=1) {
    _valueLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    _valueLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    _valueLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _valueLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    _valueLabel.font = [UIFont defaultAppFontWithSize:11];
    _valueLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    _valueLabel.text = [self yValueString:value];
    _valueLabel.tag = value;
    [self.contentView addSubview:_valueLabel];

    CGFloat multiplier = (CGFloat)(max - value) * 2.4 / (CGFloat)max;

    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_valueLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1 constant:10]];

    if (multiplier == 0) {
        _centerY = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_valueLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:35];

    } else {
        _centerY = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_valueLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:multiplier constant:35];
    }

    [self.contentView addConstraint:_centerY];
```

Later I created a horizontal scrolling collectionView that shows 5 cell custom.

In Custom Cell i have inserted a uiview with identical cell sizes the only constraint I did not enter is the uiview height because it is managed in the method

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView: (UICollectionView *) collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath: (nonnull NSIndexPath *) indexPath;
```

Each horizontal cell equals the horizontal label located on the left of the collectionView so the uiview height in the cell must be equal to the Y center of the UILabel.

This is the cellForItemAtIndexPath code

```
    -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        UDXAxisCell *xCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:xAxisCell_identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


        NSInteger max = [[_xValue valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"] integerValue];

        NSInteger n = [_xValue[indexPath.item] integerValue] ;
        UILabel *yLabelValue = (UILabel *)[self viewWithTag:n];

        CGFloat multiplier = (CGFloat)(max - n) * 2.4 / (CGFloat)max;

        xCell.heightBar.constant = yLabelValue.center.y + multiplier ;

    return xCell;
}
```

Can you help me understand how to increase the height of UIView in the cell based on the costraint of the UILabel Center Y?

---

**EDIT:** I solved this way ...

```
xCell.heightBar.constant = spaceFromTop + collectionView.frame.size.height - yLabelValue.center.y;
```

maybe if somebody can recommend better methods are always available: D